# Understanding Gradient Descent for Multivariate Linear Regression python implementation

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

It seems that the following code finds the gradient descent correctly:

```
def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations):
    xTrans = x.transpose()
    for i in range(0, numIterations):
        hypothesis = np.dot(x, theta)
        loss = hypothesis - y 
        cost = np.sum(loss ** 2) / (2 * m)
        print("Iteration %d | Cost: %f" % (i, cost))
        # avg gradient per example
        gradient = np.dot(xTrans, loss) / m 
        # update
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient
    return theta
```

Now suppose we have the following sample data:

[image]

For the 1st row of sample data, we will have:
`x = [2104, 5, 1, 45]`, `theta = [1,1,1,1]`, `y = 460`.
However, we are nowhere specifying in the lines :

```
hypothesis = np.dot(x, theta)
loss = hypothesis - y
```

which row of the sample data to consider. Then how come this code is working fine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Congrats on taking the course on Machine Learning on Coursera! :)

`hypothesis = np.dot(x,theta)` will compute the hypothesis for all x(i) at the same time, saving each h_theta(x(i)) as a row of `hypothesis`. So there is no need to reference a single row.

Same is true for `loss = hypothesis - y`.

Comment: Does this mean that x is an m*n dimensional matrix (m = no. of sample data and n = number of features) and y an m*1 matrix ?

Comment: With some cautioness: Yes! Is it possible to debug your code and take a closer look at `x` and `y`? If so, try and see yourself. I presume it is, because if `x` and `z` are not m*n or m*1, then gradient descent, as defined in this function, would not make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a slide from Andrew Ng's excellent Machine Learning course!

The code works because you're using matrix types (from the numpy library?), and the basic operators (+, -, *, /) have been overloaded to perform matrix arithmetic - therefore you don't need to iterate over each row.

Answer (score 0):

a hypothesis y  is represented by  y =  w0 + w1*x1 + w2*x2 + w3*x3 + ...... wn*xn 
where w0 is the intercept. How is the intercept figured out in hypothesis formula abose in np.dot(x, theta)

I am assuming X = data representing features. and theta can be an array like [1,1,1.,, ] of rowSize(data)